javascript- using 'this' with querySelector
Is it possible to use "this" with the  querySelector method.
I have multiple dynamic buttons on a page and need to get the data-set values for the clicked button.
<button class="user" id="1"
        data-loc="ox1"
        data-name="tom">
</button>

<button class="user" id="2"
        data-loc="ox2"
        data-name="tom-two">
</button>

I tried the below code but it only gives the first element on the page.
[...document.getElementsByClassName("user")].forEach(function(item){
        item.addEventListener("click",myFunction )
    });

 function myFunction() {
 const user = $el.querySelector(".user");
 }

I then tried using the "this" keyword but it does not work.
var $el = $(this);

const member = $el.querySelector(".user");


off topic: if you're going to use [tag:jquery] then use it: $(".user").on("click", myFunction)

this will work. You just need to use it properly. It will be the currently selected element. I don't know why you're trying to use this to lookup the element that was already clicked. https://jsbin.com/teladopide/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Don't get confused with when your variable is a jquery object or a DOM node - $el.querySelector - querySelector is not a function of a jquery object/collection - you would need to convert the jquery object to a DOM object: $el[0].querySelector (which is of course pointless as that would just be this.querySelector).   Or use jquery:  member = $el.find(".user") / member = $(".user", $el)

On a separate note, I'd urge you to consider event delegation instead of looping and assigning event listeners.

Note: this will already be .user - your html doesn't have a nested .user.  This assumes your $(this) code is inside the event handler.  If your =$(this) code is not inside myFunction (click handler) then this could be anything.  Please add some context of how your last snippet $el=$(this) is called/located within your code.  See [mcve].

"Is it possible to use "this" with the querySelector method." - yes: this.querySelector(...  depends on what this is.   $(this).querySelector - no.


No need for jQuery
Also no need for spread using querySelectorAll
you need to use the event passed in the function



document.querySelectorAll('.user').forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", myFunction)
});

function myFunction(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('button.user');
  if (!tgt) return; // not a button
  const userDiv = document.getElementById(tgt.dataset.name);
  console.log(userDiv.textContent)
}
<button class="user" id="1" data-loc="ox1" data-name="tom">Click 1</button>
<button class="user" id="2" data-loc="ox2" data-name="tom-two">Click 2</button>

<div id="tom">Tom</div>
<div id="tom-two">Tom2</div>



I recommend to delegate too


document.getElementById('buttonDiv').addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('button.user');
  if (!tgt) return; // not a button
  const userDiv = document.getElementById(tgt.dataset.name);
  console.log(userDiv.textContent)
})
<div id="buttonDiv">
  <button class="user" id="1" data-loc="ox1" data-name="tom">Click 1</button>
  <button class="user" id="2" data-loc="ox2" data-name="tom-two">Click 2</button>
</div>
<div id="tom">Tom</div>
<div id="tom-two">Tom2</div>




In an event handler, this is already set to the element the event listener was bound to (also known as event.currentTarget). There is no need to call querySelector again.
The data attributes can be accessed via the dataset property.


[...document.getElementsByClassName("user")].forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
});

function myFunction() {
  console.clear();
  console.log(this.dataset);
}
<button class="user" id="1" data-loc="ox1" data-name="tom">
        Button 1
</button>

<button class="user" id="2" data-loc="ox2" data-name="tom-two">
        Button 2
</button>



Also note that it is generally recommended to use event delegation on a common ancestor instead of attaching event listeners to every individual element.


document.querySelector('.buttons-container').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.matches('button.user')) {
    console.clear();
    console.log(e.target.dataset);
  }
});
<div class="buttons-container">
  <button class="user" id="1" data-loc="ox1" data-name="tom">
    Button 1
  </button>
  <button class="user" id="2" data-loc="ox2" data-name="tom-two">
    Button 2
  </button>
</div>




@RokoC.Buljan No need to (wrongly) assume I do not understand event delegation. 1) I did not read this anywhere. 2) The code snippet is just meant as an example, not as a template to copy and paste everywhere. One should aim to understand code before using it in one's own project. 3) I clearly used matches here because the provided HTML has buttons that only contain plain text.

I hope this approach can help you.


const myClickEventFunction = myEvent =>
{
  // Select the element that fired the event.
  const myClickedElement = myEvent.target;
  
  // Reserve the namespace for all attributes.
  const myAttributes = {};
  
  // Get the dataset attributes.
  const myDataSet = myClickedElement.dataset;
  
  // Populate myAttributes with all atrributes of myClickedElement.
  for ( const myAttribute of myClickedElement.attributes )
  {
    myAttributes[myAttribute.name] = myAttribute.value;
  }
  
  // DEBUG:
  console.clear();
  console.log('Clicked element:', myClickedElement);
  console.log('Clicked element attributes:', myAttributes);
  console.log('Clicked element dataset:', myDataSet);
}

// Select all elements with the CSS class `user`.
const myButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.user');

// Bind the myClickEventFunction to each element in myButtons.
for ( const myButtonElement of myButtons )
{
  myButtonElement.addEventListener('click', myClickEventFunction);
}
<button class="user" id="1"
        data-loc="ox1"
        data-name="tom">
        B1
</button>

<button class="user" id="2"
        data-loc="ox2"
        data-name="tom-two">
        B2
</button>





Is it possible to use "this" with the querySelector method.

It may be possible (but your question is not very clear on how you would want to use it), but anyway not desirable (using this seldom is). To simplify things, let's use event delegation, which is especially suitable for dynamically created elements.


document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  // did the event originate from the button of interest?
  const userBttn = evt.target.closest(`.user`);
  
  // if so ... handle it
  if (userBttn) {
    // retrieve and display the values of the data-attributes
    // ([Element].dataset property)
    console.log(`loc: ${userBttn.dataset.loc}, name: ${
          userBttn.dataset.name}`);
  }
}
<button class="user" id="1"
        data-loc="ox1"
        data-name="tom">
  user 1
</button>

<button class="user" id="2"
        data-loc="ox2"
        data-name="tom-two">
  user 2
</button>



